# Configuration of Mend/WhiteSource per app in monorepo

Tags: security, sca, whitesource

We are planning to use Mend (WhiteSource) to scan our code in a monorepo. The way Mend works by default is to scan all code in a monorepo after a push to master branch. Is it possible to configure Mend per app in the monorepo and not scan all apps in a monorepo for any change in any of the apps in the monorepo?